# Internal name resolution issue in Windows server 2008-

Tags: windows-server-2008, internal-dns

I have 2 dc for my domain root and additional  both of them working primary  DNS Ad integrated, yesterday I had issues that the root dc DNS records are not appearing but the other dc DNS zone appears  normally ,

I tried to restore the DNS zone but still all record hidden  please support.

Comment: Was DNS scavenging recently enabled? You can confirm in the DNS Server event log by filtering on event id 2501.  If you see a 2501 event with a lot of records scavenged, that would be the cause.

Comment: `the root dc DNS records are not appearing but the other dc DNS zone appears normally` - I don't understand this statement. Is the problem with the DNS records for one of the DC's or is the problem with the DNS zone itself?

Comment: One of the primary dns doesn't showen records in the zone but the other primary dns showing full record . I made sites  replication  and its successful replicate  but stile the first dns not showen any records

Comment: Scavenging  not enable and when i trying  to add the effected  dns server on the other console its giving error message  that this dns not available

Comment: Then i tried to delete the zone and import it from the backup which i got it from the other primary dns .also still not showen  the records . I tried to add record was exist in the network its give me error that this record is already created but its now shoen in dns